# Checking max items in mat table using checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular9, angular10

I am working on an angular application and using mat table which has mat check box. Code is as follows:

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    
      <!-- Checkbox Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="row.checked" (change)="getCheckboxesData(row)">
          </mat-checkbox>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Position Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Weight Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Symbol Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
      </tr>
    </table>

import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
  { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
  { position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N' },
  { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O' },
  { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F' },
  { position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' }
];

/**
 * @title Table with selection
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-selection-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-selection-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-selection-example.html'
})
export class TableSelectionExample {
  public data: any;
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'select',
    'position',
    'name',
    'weight',
    'symbol'
  ];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  selection = new SelectionModel<PeriodicElement>(true, []);

  /** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  getCheckboxesData(row) {
    if (row.checked === true) {
      console.log(row);
      this.data.push(row);
    }
  }
}
```

Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l4x28h?embed=1&file=app/table-selection-example.html

I want to implement a functionality in checbox so that if user clicks more than 3 checkbox(upto 3 it's fine user can check), means when user tries to check 4th checkbox then I need to show a dialog and make sure particular row data is not added in array. If user unchecks already checked box than that particular Item should be removed from array. In short, we should allow max 3 items to be checked at any time. how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you change your `getCheckboxData` function as follows:

```
getCheckboxesData(row) {
  if (row.checked === true) {
    if (!this.maxReached()) {
      // 3 selected items not reached, so add this one
      this.data.push(row);
    } else {
      // Needs to be done in a setTimeout - see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9275
      setTimeout(() => {
        // 3 selected items, so uncheck this one
        row.checked = false;
        // Display a dialog indicating there are too many items selected
        this.dialog.open(WarningDialog);
      });
    }
  } else if (row.checked === false) {
    // Remove the row
    this.data = this.data.filter(el => {
      return el.symbol !== row.symbol;
    });
  }
  console.log('selected', this.data);
}
```

This will perform a check `maxReached()` to see whether the `data` array (that holds the selected items) already contains 3 items. If it does it will uncheck the row that you just checked (doing this in a `setTimeout` function due to this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9275) and open a dialog with a message.

The `maxReached()` function just returns true if 3 items are selected, and false otherwise:

```
maxReached(): boolean {
  return this.data.length === 3;
}
```

The other bit of code I added here is the bit that removes the item from the `data` array if you unchecked a checkbox. This uses the `filter` function of Array to locate the correct element and then remove it from the array. You'll need to add a constructor to the class `TableSelectionExample` to inject the service needed to open the modal:

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}
```

The code for the model is as follows:

**Typescript**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'warning-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'warning-dialog.html'
})
export class WarningDialog {}
```

**HTML**

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Too Many Selected</h2>
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
  <p>You can only select a maximum of 3 elements</p>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

Don't forget to add the `WarningDialog` to `entryComponents` and `declarations` in your `AppModule` class.

There's a working StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l4x28h-ezgmob?embed=1&file=app/table-selection-example.html).